# why vector template function assign has two version to distinguish

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm reading the source code of SGI STL. When I read the source code of assign implementation, I found that there are two versions, one for input iterator the other for forward iterator. I know that input iterator support read and ++, forward iterator support read and write and ++, why it have two version for input and forward iterator?

```
template <class _Tp, class _Alloc> template <class _InputIter>
void vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_assign_aux(_InputIter __first, _InputIter __last,
                                    input_iterator_tag) {
  iterator __cur = begin();
  for ( ; __first != __last && __cur != end(); ++__cur, ++__first)
    *__cur = *__first;
  if (__first == __last)
    erase(__cur, end());
  else
    insert(end(), __first, __last);
}

template <class _Tp, class _Alloc> template <class _ForwardIter>
void
vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_assign_aux(_ForwardIter __first, _ForwardIter __last,
                               forward_iterator_tag) {
  size_type __len = 0;
  distance(__first, __last, __len);

  if (__len > capacity()) {
    iterator __tmp = _M_allocate_and_copy(__len, __first, __last);
    destroy(_M_start, _M_finish);
    _M_deallocate(_M_start, _M_end_of_storage - _M_start);
    _M_start = __tmp;
    _M_end_of_storage = _M_finish = _M_start + __len;
  }
  else if (size() >= __len) {
    iterator __new_finish = copy(__first, __last, _M_start);
    destroy(__new_finish, _M_finish);
    _M_finish = __new_finish;
  }
  else {
    _ForwardIter __mid = __first;
    advance(__mid, size());
    copy(__first, __mid, _M_start);
    _M_finish = uninitialized_copy(__mid, __last, _M_finish);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know that input iterator support read and ++, forward iterator
>   support read and write and ++

Not quite. The key point here is that forward iterators are *multipass*. You can only iterate over (non-forward) input iterators once, whereas you can iterate through forward iterators multiple times.

This means that with forward iterators, it is possible to use `distance()` to obtain the number of elements in the new range in advance, allocate the necessary amount of memory if needed, and then iterate over the range again and copy over the elements. This guarantees that you reallocate at most once.

With input iterators, you can't do this, because the `distance()` call would have iterated over the range, and you can't iterate over it again to actually read the elements.